# JAHMM Package Maven

Tags: java, maven, machine-learning

I need to work with  be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm package for Hidden Markov Models in java.

My project is a mevenized project so I need to use the corresponding dependency.

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jahmm</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
       </dependency>
```

The above dependency is not being resolved in my project.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency is not in the Maven Central Repository.

Find out the repository used by the authors to publish their artifacts and add this repository to your POM or to your `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not published to the usual online maven repositories, you will need to install it on your local machine first.

So download the sources, go to the top level and do the usual

```
 mvn install
```

Once you installed `jahmm` locally, your project can resolve it from your maven cache.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this repository should do the trick:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jsi</id>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-remote</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jahmm</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```